# I can't seem to get a object to pull another variable object when the class is created?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to create two var one var is a object that gets another object inside the same class

```
package plus1 
{

public class ScreenInfo 
{

    //setting a button to 0 means that it is disabled 

    public var object:Object = { button1:_Object2 };

    public var _Object2:Object = { name:"test name" };                          

    public function ScreenInfo() 
    {

    }


}

}
```

but ever time i do this

```
var screens:ScreenInfo = new ScreenInfo(); 
var obj:Object = screens.object["button1"]
```

the object is null why is this shouldn't it pass me the second object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using variable initializers, you can't safely use references to other members. How do you know that `_Object2` exists when you create `object` ?

I suggest you move the instantiation of `object` in the constructor of your class :

```
public var object:Object;
public var _Object2:Object = { name:"test name" };

public function ScreenInfo(){
    this.object = {button1:_Object2};
}
```

Comment: is there a way to run the screeninfo function to run completely before because i can't seem to get _object2 if they are both in the constructor function its. Am a making any sense?